# Jenkins - conditions between build steps

Tags: build, hudson, build-automation, jenkins

I want to build a Maven project using Jenkins. However, the project only must be built if a certain file in the SVN repository has changed (and contains a special key)

So my plan is to create a job with two build steps:

- the first step executes a shell or python script that checks that "condition".
- the second step is the actual Maven build

The second step only must be invoked if the condition check in step 1 returned "true".

Is there a possibility to do so? Well, I guess I could return an exit code 1 in the first script if the condition is not met. This will stop the build at once, but the job will be marked as "failed". So this is not a good idea since the red icon makes my users panic ;-)

Any other ideas around this?

Cheers,
Frank

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We do something similar with our own Jenkins setup.

We have a "trigger" job that monitors SVN on a periodic basis.  When a change occurs in SVN, the trigger job executes its build steps.  One of the build steps examines some aspects of the code and decides whether a build is necessary or not.  If it is necessary, it uses CURL to initiate the start of a the "build" project.  The "build" project gets the source code and does a build - it doesn't bother to figure out whether it needs to build or not - it always does.

Having the two tasks separate also makes it easy to trigger a manual build without worrying the should-I-build logic kicking and stopping the build.