# Jenkins: stop job at the middle from powershell

Tags: powershell, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have a Jenkins job which executes several powershell scripts, with the help of powershell plugin for jenkins (each script is in a different stage of the job).

In one of the stages there's an `if` condition, if this condition evaluates to `true`, I need to stop the job and mark it as success.

Here's the relevant part in the powershell script in the relevant stage:

```
# ....        
$is_after_restart = $content
    if ($is_after_restart -eq "true")
    {
        # Need to mark build as success and abort it.
    }
```

How can this be achieved?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using multiple build steps, You can conditionally execute other build steps by using this plugin. [Jenkins Conditional Branch Step Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Conditional+BuildStep+Plugin).

If you just need to exit the current script and execute other scripts, please use this code.

```
$is_after_restart = $content
if ($is_after_restart -eq "true")
{
    exit 0
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm using multiple build steps, so I must use external plugin? There  isn't other solution?

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6018619/jenkins-conditions-between-build-steps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6018619/jenkins-conditions-between-build-steps) Hope this will answer your question.

Answer (score 1):

To stop the script and valudate the exitcode you can do something like this:

```
$is_after_restart = $content
if ($is_after_restart -eq "true")
{
    exit 0
}
```

0 is the standard exitcode for sucess.
Although you can choose whatever exitcode you want to check in jenkins and replace the 0.

Comment: This only exit the current step/stage and goes to the next one. it does not finish the entire job.